# htaccess - Is this Correct?

Tags: .htaccess

Have looked through various articles both here and elsewhere but 
could do with confirmation regards the way I have set up htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} orange [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .* blocked.php [L]
```

Can someone please confirm that given the code above that it will
block any domain, subdomain or page with the word orange in it?

It looks to be working but I need to ensure that I have covered all
bases and that I am blocking any link from or any image hotlinked from
my site where there is orange anywhere in the domain.

BTW I thought that if I have only one condition that I can leave out
the ,OR but when I removed it then it did not work in the test I was
doing??? Anyone know why this would not work without the ,OR ??

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone please confirm that given the code above that it will block any domain, subdomain or page with the word orange in it?

Yes, it will rewrite all requests to the `/blocked.php` script as long as "orange" is in the referer. The "Referer" header is what browsers typically include in a request letting the webserver know what page/site they were just at that linked to the resource that they're requesting. That means if there's a site called "orange.com" that has a page that links to one of your pages, and someone clicks on it, the referer will contain that orange.com page and the rules you have will block them.

You don't need the `OR` flag. Leaving it out works for me when the referer contains the word "orange". Just keep in mind that referers can be spoofed and it isn't a guarantee.

Comment: Thanks very much for the confirmation - appreciated!